# How to replace the default browser button in input type='date' in react with a custom button to mimic the same action?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript

So I am trying to design a custom date picker using input type='date'. I wanted to replace the default calendar icon with a custom button. How should I write the onClick handler for the button to set the value in the input field. Also the placeholder dosen't seem to work for the date input
, is there any alternative for that?

```
     <input type = 'date' placeholder='Enter Date'(doesn't work) onChange={} />
     <CalendarButton onClick={} />
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
input[type="date"]::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator{
  content: url(https://img.icons8.com/color/344/calendar--v2.png);
}
input[type='date']:before{
  content: attr(placeholder)
}
input::-webkit-datetime-edit{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input type = 'date' placeholder='Enter Date' onChange={} />
```

Comment: But this won't work in all browsers.

Comment: Yes right, it will work with the browser who uses the webkit rendering engine ie. chrome, opera and safari.

Comment: How can I use an imported icon in place of url?

Comment: Just use the path of imported icon instead of url, that's it.